# Declare a struct defined in class

Tags: c++, class, struct

There is a header file:

```
class btCollisionWorld
{
public:

    struct RayResultCallback{
        int something; //example only
    };
)
```

I'm writing another headeer file, where I want to use pointer to `btCollisionWorld
::RayResultCallback`, but I don't want to include whole `btCollisionWorld.h` (I will include it in my cpp file)

How do I declare it properly?

I've tried this and it fails:

```
class btCollisionWorld;
struct  btCollisionWorld::ClosestRayResultCallback;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't declare a struct defined inside a class without defining the containing class. You can use a namespace to achieve a similar goal.

Answer (score 0):

It's only reasonable to keep this other file seperated from the `btCollisionWorld.h` if it does not really rely on the specific class `btCollisionWorld`, but rather just on some class with certain properties which `btCollisionWorld` fulfills. In this case, it might be better to keep it generic, that is: rather than using a `btCollisionWorld*` you may do

```
template <typename btCollisionWorldT>
whatever-kind-of-structure-it-is {
  btCollisionWorldT * genericpointer;
}
```

If the structure is a class, you can later `typedef` it so that `btCollisionWorldT` is `btCollisionWorld` in every actual instance of this class.

Alternatively you can use a `void*`, but that is less likely to be the ideal solution.

Comment: Thanks, btCollisionWorld is from third party library, so I don't want to change it to different namespace etc.  
I'm just trying to reduce compile time to minimum, by removing headers included in another header file.

Comment: Are you sure ommiting it does significantly improve the compile time at all? The second `#include` shouldn't do much more anyway than open the file, run into the include guard which knows that `btCollisionWorld` has already been included, and therefore close the file again.